# Immutablejs within plain objects - Monads

Tags: functional-programming, immutable.js, folktale

The redux best practices says not to mix plain javascript object with immutablejs objects. I'm trying my hand at functional programming and it seems like the monads require the computations/values to be stored inside an object, or some container of sorts. AFAIK immutablejs maps can't store methods. Are there any issues with using FP libraries like Folktale? I haven't noticed any noticeable issues with the basic todo app (which is all I can try at the moment), so I'm hoping for some clarification on immutablejs best practices, hopefully FP leaning.

[Never mix plain JavaScript objects with Immutable.JS](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingImmutableJS.html#immutable-js-best-practices)

Comment: Did  you try a small experiment?

Comment: Yes, with the standard todo app and found no issues. But I'm not sure if that's because the app is too simple of a test case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I feel like a fool. I read the linked article again and saw that it's not about performance, but to avoid confusion as to when data passed is immutable or a pojo. Here's the relevant section from the article

> In fact, sometimes you might be tempted to put a normal JavaScript object inside an Immutable map. Don't do this. Mixing immutable and mutable state in the same object will reap confusion.

http://jlongster.com/Using-Immutable-Data-Structures-in-JavaScript